# Performance -- Attunity's Teradata Connector for Microsoft

Tags: sql-server, ssis, teradata, attunity

I haven't been able to find a non-advocated performance evaluation for the  Attunity Teradata connectors for Microsoft. I found a before and after comparison for Oracle that showed rows per second. But, I've not found anything like that for Teradata.

What are your experiences using Attunity to transfer data *FROM* Teradata *TO* SQL Server? Right now, I will be happy with an answer that gives only a rough order of magnitude. But if you can provide actual values like rows per second that would be preferred.

Background:
I realize it is a rather subjective question. But, I need more information to aid in deciding if it is worth upgrading from SQL Server Standard edition to Enterprise edition just for these drivers.

We are using SQL Server 2014 and Teradata 15 on our servers. We have several net-change data pulls every 30 minutes from Teradata to SQL Server. We also have several batch jobs that run at night.

Comment: regardless of performance anywhere else, you'd have to test in in your own environment.  Performance of the Attunity driver using native Tdata methods should beat performance over ODBC and .NET drivers, but it may be by a negligible amount.

Comment: I  was able to upgrade my dev server to SQL Server EE. For a quick and dirty evaluation, I ran one of my weekend jobs with the old providers and attunity a few times each.

My before setup - TD.Net (15.0) to SQLNCLI11 took around 6 hours.

My after setup - Attunity connector for Teradata 3.0 to SQL Server OLEDB took around 22 minutes.